# How to match a number and a string in another line with regex in python?

Tags: python, regex

I am a newbie in regular expressions. I have a text with a lot of lines like that:

```
first line
2
It is more
a lot of other lines
```

How can I match the second line and a part of the third line with regex?
I want to match "2 It is".
Any ideas?

I tried

```
re.compile(r'2&\n It is')
```

Comment: Remove the `&` symbol, you have no `&` after `2` in your string. I am not even sure you have a space before `It`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `(\d\nIt is)` is the pattern that you need.
see https://regex101.com/r/NizJRT/1
When we run the following script

```
import re

myText = 'first line\n2\nIt is more\na lot of other lines'
found = re.search(r'(\d\nIt is)',myText)
for f in found.groups():
  print(f)
```

the output is

```
2
It is
```